# Sort large arrays of primitive types in descending order

Tags: java, sorting

I've got a **large** array of primitive types (double).
How do I sort the elements in **descending order**?

Unfortunately the Java API doesn't support sorting of **primitive** types with a Comparator.

The first approach that probably comes to mind is to convert it to a list of objects (boxing):

```
double[] array = new double[1048576];    
Arrays.stream(array).boxed().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())…
```

This solution is probably good enough for many (or even most) use cases but **boxing** each primitive in the array is **too slow and causes a lot of GC pressure** if the array is large!

Another approach would be to sort and then reverse:

```
double[] array = new double[1048576];
...
Arrays.sort(array);
// reverse the array
for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
     // swap the elements
     double temp = array[i];
     array[i] = array[array.length - (i + 1)];
     array[array.length - (i + 1)] = temp;
}
```

**This approach can also be too slow** if the array is already sorted quite well.

What's a better alternative if the arrays are large and performance is the major optimization goal?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Java Primitive](https://github.com/mintern-java/primitive#java-primitive) includes functionality for sorting primitive arrays based on a custom comparator. Using it, and Java 8, your sample could be written as:

```
double[] array = new double[1048576];
...
Primitive.sort(array, (d1, d2) -> Double.compare(d2, d1), false);
```

If you're using Maven, you can include it with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.mintern</groupId>
    <artifactId>primitive</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When you pass `false` as the third argument to `sort`, it uses an unstable sort, a simple edit of Java's built-in [dual-pivot quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Variants). This means that the speed should be close to that of built-in sorting.

Full disclosure: I wrote the Java Primitive library.

Comment: This is a great, simple project on GitHub.  Very nice work!  Readers should also note that `true` as third argument to `sort` will use a simple edit of Java's built-in TimSort, which is stable.

Answer (score 29):

I think it would be best not to re-invent the wheel and use Arrays.sort().

Yes, I saw the "descending" part. The sorting is the hard part, and you want to benefit from the simplicity and speed of Java's library code. Once that's done, you simply reverse the array, which is a relatively cheap O(n) operation. [Here's some code](http://www.leepoint.net/data/arrays/arrays-ex-reverse.html) I found to do this in as little as 4 lines:

```
for (int left=0, right=b.length-1; left<right; left++, right--) {
    // exchange the first and last
    int temp = b[left]; b[left]  = b[right]; b[right] = temp;
}
```

Comment: this answer should be accepted. It is much faster than the alternatives (boxing + sorting + unboxing, with or without streams)

Comment: Sorting plus reversing the array is actually even a potential solution that you find in my question. It’s probably a good enough solution for most cases. However, in the case that I was asking for, speed really mattered and it was likely that the array was already sorted. In this case, reversing the array is a significant overhead even if it’s only a O(n) operation. In the end an optimization such as using "Java Primitive" should certainly only be applied if a good benchmark shows that it’s really worth the costs (e.g. the extra dependency).

Answer (score 14):

Heres a one-liner, using streams in Java 8

```
int arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Comment: **Boxing** each primitive in the array is too expensive for large arrays!

Comment: Excellent, thanks. It's good to have a working one-liner with standard java methods. If it's indeed too slow for large arrays, it's always possible to refactor it.

Answer (score 8):

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) has methods for converting primitive arrays to Lists of wrapper types. The nice part is that these lists are live views, so operations on them work on the underlying arrays as well (similar to `Arrays.asList()`, but for primitives).

Anyway, each of these Lists can be passed to `Collections.reverse()`:

```
int[] intArr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
float[] floatArr = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f };
double[] doubleArr = { 1.0d, 2.0d, 3.0d, 4.0d, 5.0d };
byte[] byteArr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
short[] shortArr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Collections.reverse(Ints.asList(intArr));
Collections.reverse(Floats.asList(floatArr));
Collections.reverse(Doubles.asList(doubleArr));
Collections.reverse(Bytes.asList(byteArr));
Collections.reverse(Shorts.asList(shortArr));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArr));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(floatArr));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doubleArr));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteArr));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shortArr));
```

Output:

> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>   [5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
>   [5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
>   [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>   [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

Comment: `Ints.asList(intArr).sort()` creates a copy of the underlying array and sorts the copy.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation (the one in the question) is faster than e.g. wrapping with `toList()` and using a comparator-based method.  Auto-boxing and running through comparator methods or wrapped Collections objects is far slower than just reversing.

Of course you could write your own sort.  That might not be the answer you're looking for, *but* note that if your comment about "if the array is already sorted quite well" happens frequently, you might do well to choose a sorting algorithm that handles that case well (e.g. insertion) rather than use `Arrays.sort()` (which is mergesort, or insertion if the number of elements is small).

Comment: You can't call Arrays.toList on a double[] and have it do what you want; Arrays.toList needs to be passed a Double[] and not an array of primitive types.

Comment: Arrays.asList(new double[]{}); compiles ok.

Comment: That's my point; I summarize this problem in my newly-edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Comparators for sorting primitive arrays.

Your best bet is to implement (or borrow an implementation) of a sorting algorithm that is [appropriate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Summaries_of_popular_sorting_algorithms)  for your use case to sort the array (in reverse order in your case).

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest solution is still:

1. Getting the natural order of the array
2. Finding the maximum within that sorted array which is then the last item
3. Using a for-loop with decrement operator

As said by others before: using toList is additional effort, Arrays.sort(array,Collections.reverseOrder()) doesn't work with primitives and using an extra framework seems too complicated when all you need is already inbuild and therefore probably faster as well...

Sample code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SimpleDescending {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // unsorted array
        int[] integerList = {55, 44, 33, 88, 99};

        // Getting the natural (ascending) order of the array
        Arrays.sort(integerList);

        // Getting the last item of the now sorted array (which represents the maximum, in other words: highest number)
        int max = integerList.length-1;

        // reversing the order with a simple for-loop
        System.out.println("Array in descending order:");
        for(int i=max; i>=0; i--) {
            System.out.println(integerList[i]);
        }

        // You could make the code even shorter skipping the variable max and use
        // "int i=integerList.length-1" instead of int "i=max" in the parentheses of the for-loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Before sorting the given array multiply each element by -1
```

then use Arrays.sort(arr) then again multiply each element by -1

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    arr[i]=-arr[i];
Arrays.sort(arr);
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    arr[i]=-arr[i];
```

Comment: Sadly doesn't work with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`: https://ideone.com/HBcrI8

Comment: `int[] sorted = IntStream.of(arr).map(i -> ~i).sorted().map(i -> ~i).toArray();` works

Comment: @user4910279 I initially cringed at your use of streams, but I did some benchmarking and found the stream is only a bit slower than working on the arrays directly (the difference is around 15%).

Answer (score 1):

There's been some confusion about `Arrays.asList` in the other answers.  If you say

```
double[] arr = new double[]{6.0, 5.0, 11.0, 7.0};
List xs = Arrays.asList(arr);
System.out.println(xs.size());  // prints 1
```

then you'll have a List with 1 element.  The resulting List has the double[] array as its own element.  What you want is to have a `List<Double>` whose elements are the elements of the `double[]`.

Unfortunately, no solution involving Comparators will work for a primitive array.  `Arrays.sort` only accepts a Comparator when being passed an `Object[]`.  And for the reasons describe above, `Arrays.asList` won't let you make a List out of the elements of your array.

So despite my earlier answer which the comments below reference, there's no better way than manually reversing the array after sorting.  Any other approach (such as copying the elements into a `Double[]` and reverse-sorting and copying them back) would be more code and slower.

Comment: No apology necessary.  Editing your answers to make them better is what SO is all about.  I even upvoted your answer because it's the one that seems to be getting the most discussion.

Comment: doesn't compile with array = double[]{}

Comment: I tried the same as both @jjnguy & @Eli - I think Arrays.asList() will be more performant than manually converting double[] to Double[] which would require boxing for every element - right...

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect my findings after writing some test programs.

Comment: I just realized this after writing my own test program...
I think the answer here is to just use python, which doesn't have this silly primitive vs. object distinction =).

Comment: Ha, I was really tempted to say something in my answer about how this problem doesn't exist in Python, but I held off due to not wanting to start a language flame war.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is important, and the list usually already is sorted quite well.

Bubble sort should be one of the slowest ways of sorting, but I have seen cases where the best performance was a simple bi-directional bubble sort.

So this may be one of the few cases where you can benefit from coding it yourself. But you really need to do it right (make sure at least somebody else confirms your code, make a proof that it works etc.)

As somebody else pointed out, it may be even better to start with a sorted array, and keep it sorted while you change the contents. That may perform even better.

Answer (score 1):

With numerical types, negating the elements before and after sort seems an option. Speed relative to a single reverse after sort depends on cache, and if reverse is not faster, any difference may well be lost in noise.

Comment: add comment rather posting comment as answer.

Comment: Now that I've got enough reputation to comment, I still think this is an answer: it describes `How [to] sort the elements in descending order`, and with `sort and then reverse […] is slow`, I think it's one alternative to measure the speed of. What makes it a comment rather than an answer in your eyes?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any primitive sorting facilities within the Java core API.

From my experimentations with the [D programming language](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/gp4/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=dlang&lang2=java) (a sort of C on steroids), I've found that the merge sort algorithm is arguably the fastest general-purpose sorting algorithm around (it's what the D language itself uses to implement its sort function).

- [One implementation in Java](http://www.koders.com/java/fid33A9899502EA6621A9E4CD88C33C600F0602C211.aspx?s=cdef:tree)
- [Another implementation](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/applications/Mergesort.java)
- [One more implementation](http://users.dickinson.edu/~braught/courses/cs132f02/code/MergeSort.src.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is correct. But we can do optimization as follows:
While reversing, You may try keeping another variable to reduce backward counter since computing of array.length-(i+1) may take time!
And also move declaration of temp outside so that everytime it needs not to be allocated

```
double temp;

for(int i=0,j=array.length-1; i < (array.length/2); i++, j--) {

     // swap the elements
     temp = array[i];
     array[i] = array[j];
     array[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: storing the array length (and the half array length) in variables outside the loop is worthwhile.  declaring 'temp' outside the loop makes no difference whatsover - there's no "allocation" involved.

Answer (score 0):

for small arrays this may work.

```
int getOrder (double num, double[] array){
    double[] b = new double[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        b[i] = array[i];
    }
    Arrays.sort(b);
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
        if ( num < b[i]) return i;
    }
    return b.length;
}
```

I was surprised that the initial loading of array b was necessary

```
double[] b = array; // makes b point to array. so beware!
```

Answer (score 0):

If using java8, just convert array to stream, sort and convert back.
All of the tasks can be done just in one line, so I feel this way is not too bad.

```
double[] nums = Arrays.stream(nums).boxed().
        .sorted((i1, i2) -> Double.compare(i2, i1))
        .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
        .toArray();
```

Comment: Boxing is too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, a better and more concise approach could be:

```
double[] arr = {13.6, 7.2, 6.02, 45.8, 21.09, 9.12, 2.53, 100.4};

Double[] boxedarr = Arrays.stream( arr ).boxed().toArray( Double[]::new );
Arrays.sort(boxedarr, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(boxedarr));
```

This would give the reversed array and is more presentable.

Input: [13.6, 7.2, 6.02, 45.8, 21.09, 9.12, 2.53, 100.4]

Output: [100.4, 45.8, 21.09, 13.6, 9.12, 7.2, 6.02, 2.53]

Comment: It would have been better if the downvoter could have just explained his problem with this solution or could have corrected me incase of a better answer before just blankly down voting.

Answer (score 0):

Understand it's a very old post but I stumbled upon a similar problem trying to sort primitive int arrays, so posting my solution. Suggestions/comments welcome -

```
int[] arr = {3,2,1,3};
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(i -> list.add(i));
list.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double s =-1;
   double[] n = {111.5, 111.2, 110.5, 101.3, 101.9, 102.1, 115.2, 112.1};
   for(int i = n.length-1;i>=0;--i){
      int k = i-1;
      while(k >= 0){
          if(n[i]>n[k]){
              s = n[k];
              n[k] = n[i];
              n[i] = s;
          }
          k --;
      }
   }
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));
 it gives time complexity O(n^2) but i hope its work
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full program that sorts objects based on a inner field.

```
package Algorithms.BranchAndBound;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class KnapSack01 {
    private class ItemVals {
        double weight;
        double cost;
        double ratio;

        public ItemVals(double weight, double cost) {
            this.weight = weight;
            this.cost = cost;
            this.ratio = weight/cost;
        }
    }

    public ItemVals[] createSortedItemVals(double[] weight, double[] cost) {
        ItemVals[] itemVals = new ItemVals[weight.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < weight.length; i++) {
            ItemVals itemval = new ItemVals(weight[i], cost[i]);
            itemVals[i] = itemval;
        }
        Arrays.sort(itemVals, new Comparator<ItemVals>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ItemVals o1, ItemVals o2) {
                return Double.compare(o2.ratio, o1.ratio);
            }
        });
        return itemVals;
    }

    public void printItemVals(ItemVals[] itemVals) {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemVals.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(itemVals[i].ratio);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KnapSack01 knapSack01 = new KnapSack01();
        double[] weight = {2, 3.14, 1.98, 5, 3};
        double[] cost = {40, 50, 100, 95, 30};
        ItemVals[] itemVals = knapSack01.createSortedItemVals(weight, cost);
        knapSack01.printItemVals(itemVals);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Double[] d = {5.5, 1.3, 8.8};
Arrays.sort(d, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d));
```

Collections.reverseOrder() doesn't work on primitives, but Double, Integer etc works with Collections.reverseOrder()

Answer (score -1):

Below is my solution, you can adapt it to your needs.

How does it work? It takes an array of integers as arguments. After that it will create a new array which will contain the same values as the array from the arguments. The reason of doing this is to leave the original array intact.

Once the new array contains the copied data, we sort it by swapping the values until the condition *if(newArr[i] < newArr[i+1])* evaluates to false. That means the array is sorted in descending order.

For a thorough explanation check my blog post [here](http://csforfun.com/llsn-sort-array-descending-order).

```
public static int[] sortDescending(int[] array)
{
    int[] newArr = new int[array.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        newArr[i] = array[i];
    }

    boolean flag = true;
    int tempValue;

    while(flag) 
    {
        flag = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < newArr.length - 1; i++) 
        {
            if(newArr[i] < newArr[i+1])
            {
                tempValue = newArr[i];
                newArr[i] = newArr[i+1];
                newArr[i+1] = tempValue;
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: writing your own sort is not a good idea - it is much slower than the library one

Answer (score -2):

```
double[] array = new double[1048576];
```

...

By default order is ascending

To reverse the order

```
Arrays.sort(array,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder());` is a good solution but it will **NOT** work on  primitives. It will only work on a `class`.

Comment: Not a solution for primitive type

Comment: this will not work on primitive types, this is for object types.