# Sort an array instead of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, processing

I have an array, not an arrayList and I would like to sort it.
This only tells me that Collections are not applicable for the arguments (pixelPlaceSort.Pixel[], ...etc.

```
Collections.sort(pixels, new PixelComparator());
```

I could use a List to solve it but for the purpose of learning I don't want that.

So how can this work?
c is an int.

```
class PixelComparator implements Comparator<Pixel> {

  PixelComparator() {
  }

  public int compare(Pixel p1, Pixel p2) {
    if(p1.c < p2.c) {
      return -1; 
    } else if(p1.c > p2.c) {
      return 1; 
    }
    else {
      return 0; 
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: Next time try Google first! "java sort array" might have worked

Comment: tons of duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694751/java-array-sort-descending, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215271/sort-arrays-of-primitive-types-in-descending-order etc etc

Comment: i really did a search! Found mostly stuff where Integer would be used to solve the problem or convert to list and convert back. But maybe i should have searched some longer, sry for that then

Answer (score 6):

you can use `Arrays.sort(Object[] array)` or `Arrays.sort(Object[] array,Comparator c)`

Answer (score 1):

For that you have a class called **Arrays**.

Use **Arrays.sort(pixels)** 
Or **Arrays.sort(pixels,new PixelComparator())**

Check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) for java.util.Arrays and chose the appropriate form of the sort() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Arrays class - specifically this [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

you got 2 options to sort this.

**1- Keeping your Array:**

your use the [sort method of the "Arrays" Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

```
Arrays.sort(pixels,new PixelComparator());
```

**2- Using instead a List**

you first convert your array to an List and then sort it:

```
ArrayList<Pixel> pixellist  = new ArrayList<Pixel>(Arrays.asList(pixels));
Collections.sort(pixellist, new PixelComparator());
```