# Sort an array of primitives with a custom comparator and without converting to objects

Tags: java

What's the simplest way to sort a primitive array in Java with a custom comparator (or key) function and *without converting to an array of objects* (for performance †).

† (Just a precaution, I'm not asking whether not converting to objects is a good decision from a performance POV.)

Comment: Try implementing quicksort (or just take any implementation from the web). On the side node, Collections.sort() uses mergesort.

Comment: I _believe_ (why this isn't an answer) that you can use the `Object` representation of the primitive with the `Arrays.sort()` method... For example, you could use `Long` for `long[]`.  Haven't tried it and I could be wrong though...I'm not sure whether an array of primitives could transparently convert to an array of the corresponding object.

Comment: Collections.sort() used to use merge sort but now it uses "TimSort" although there's some stuff in the API that you can call if you want to use the legacy merge sort.

Comment: fhucho are you asking if there's a library way to do this? If so then there's not. Comparator interface will require conversion to an object. darijan's answer is getting a +1 from me. The "simplest way" is to implement a good sort algorithm yourself, comparing the way you want.

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate but the discussion here may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215271/sort-arrays-of-primitive-types-in-descending-order

Comment: @ScottShipp yes, I was mostly looking for a lib. You're right, it looks like I'll have to implement it by myself.

Comment: OUt of curiosity: what kind of order you're using that is a proped full ordering order and is distinct from the the usual order.

Comment: @ScottShipp TimSort still is a variant of MergeSort.

Answer (score 6):

Sorting of an array of primitive values *with a custom comparator* is not supported by the standard Java libraries.

You could easily implement your a simple sort ( e.g. bubblesort - `O(N^2)` ) from scratch, but the problem is that for large enough arrays the saving you make by not converting to boxed types is lost in the less efficient sorting algorithm.

So your choices are:

- Implement a high performance sort (mergesort, modified quicksort, etc) from scratch.
- Find an existing high performance sort for primitive types that doesn't support comparators, and modify it.
- See if you can find a suitable 3rd-party library that supports ptimitive arrays and comparators.  (I haven't managed to find one ...)

(Note: the `Comparator` interface won't work here.  It is not suitable for comparing primitive types.)

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can have your sort method take a function interface. This is modified code from OpenJDK (Copyright 1997-2007 Sun Microsystems, Inc. [GPLv2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html)):

```
import java.util.function.LongBinaryOperator;

public class ArraySort {
    public static void sort(long[] x, LongBinaryOperator op) {
        sort1(x, 0, x.length, op);
    }

    private static void sort1(long x[], int off, int len, LongBinaryOperator op) {
        if (len < 7) {
            for (int i=off; i<len+off; i++)
                // Use custom comparator for insertion sort fallback
                for (int j=i; j>off && (op.applyAsLong(x[j-1], x[j]) > 0); j--)
                    swap(x, j, j-1);
            return;
        }

        int m = off + (len >> 1);
        if (len > 7) {
            int l = off;
            int n = off + len - 1;
            if (len > 40) {
                int s = len/8;
                l = med3(x, l,     l+s, l+2*s);
                m = med3(x, m-s,   m,   m+s);
                n = med3(x, n-2*s, n-s, n);
            }
            m = med3(x, l, m, n);
        }
        long v = x[m];

        int a = off, b = a, c = off + len - 1, d = c;
        while(true) {
            // Use custom comparator for checking elements
            while (b <= c && (op.applyAsLong(x[b], v) <= 0)) {
                if (x[b] == v)
                    swap(x, a++, b);
                b++;
            }
            // Use custom comparator for checking elements
            while (c >= b && (op.applyAsLong(x[c], v) >= 0)) {
                if (x[c] == v)
                    swap(x, c, d--);
                c--;
            }
            if (b > c)
                break;
            swap(x, b++, c--);
        }

        int s, n = off + len;
        s = Math.min(a-off, b-a  );  vecswap(x, off, b-s, s);
        s = Math.min(d-c,   n-d-1);  vecswap(x, b,   n-s, s);

        if ((s = b-a) > 1)
            sort1(x, off, s, op);
        if ((s = d-c) > 1)
            sort1(x, n-s, s, op);
    }

    private static void swap(long x[], int a, int b) {
        long t = x[a];
        x[a] = x[b];
        x[b] = t;
    }

    private static void vecswap(long x[], int a, int b, int n) {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++, a++, b++)
            swap(x, a, b);
    }

    private static int med3(long x[], int a, int b, int c) {
        return (x[a] < x[b] ?
                (x[b] < x[c] ? b : x[a] < x[c] ? c : a) :
                (x[b] > x[c] ? b : x[a] > x[c] ? c : a));
    }
}
```

And call it with lambdas or anything else implementing the `LongBinaryOperator` interface:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long x[] = {5, 5, 7, 1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 23, 5, 32, 45, 76};
        ArraySort.sort(x, (a, b) -> b - a);         // sort descending
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[76, 45, 32, 23, 9, 8, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Be aware that since the above is copied (with modification) from the Sun / Oracle GPLv2 codebase, if >you< use it in your application, then your application is also subject to the GPLv2 constraints.  In short, if you distribute binaries, you must also make your source code available.  If you don't understand this talk to a lawyer.  (Note that Oracle has a reputation for being legally aggressive ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can just build your own compare functions ,
 and use one of the sort algorithms

easiest and slowest: [BubbleSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) ( O(N^2) ).

hardest but fastest : [MergeSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)( (O(Nlog(n) ) .

now in both algos you have the part that asks if A > B , in this part you should put your compare func.

```
boolean compare(int x, int y){
     if(/* your crazy compare condition */)
         return true;
     else return false; 
}
```

example in bubble sort :

```
    procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
   repeat     
     swapped = false
     for i = 1 to length(A) - 1 inclusive do:
       /* if this pair is out of order */
       if compare(A[i],A[i-1]) then // Notcie the compare instead of A[i] > A[i-1]
         /* swap them and remember something changed */
         swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
         swapped = true
       end if
     end for
   until not swapped
end procedure
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of Integer representing the indexes in the array, sort the list. You can reuse the list of indexes many times for many sorts.

Comment: That's a clever idea, I might use it.

Comment: how is this better than boxing the primitives?

Answer (score 0):

I copied the following from Java 6's Arrays.java and modified it to my needs. It uses insertion sort on smaller arrays so it should be faster than pure quicksort.

```
/**
 * Sorts the specified sub-array of integers into ascending order.
 */
private static void sort1(int x[], int off, int len) {
    // Insertion sort on smallest arrays
    if (len < 7) {
        for (int i=off; i<len+off; i++)
            for (int j=i; j>off && x[j-1]>x[j]; j--)
                swap(x, j, j-1);
        return;
    }

    // Choose a partition element, v
    int m = off + (len >> 1);       // Small arrays, middle element
    if (len > 7) {
        int l = off;
        int n = off + len - 1;
        if (len > 40) {        // Big arrays, pseudomedian of 9
            int s = len/8;
            l = med3(x, l,     l+s, l+2*s);
            m = med3(x, m-s,   m,   m+s);
            n = med3(x, n-2*s, n-s, n);
        }
        m = med3(x, l, m, n); // Mid-size, med of 3
    }
    int v = x[m];

    // Establish Invariant: v* (<v)* (>v)* v*
    int a = off, b = a, c = off + len - 1, d = c;
    while(true) {
        while (b <= c && x[b] <= v) {
            if (x[b] == v)
                swap(x, a++, b);
            b++;
        }
        while (c >= b && x[c] >= v) {
            if (x[c] == v)
                swap(x, c, d--);
            c--;
        }
        if (b > c)
            break;
        swap(x, b++, c--);
    }

    // Swap partition elements back to middle
    int s, n = off + len;
    s = Math.min(a-off, b-a  );  vecswap(x, off, b-s, s);
    s = Math.min(d-c,   n-d-1);  vecswap(x, b,   n-s, s);

    // Recursively sort non-partition-elements
    if ((s = b-a) > 1)
        sort1(x, off, s);
    if ((s = d-c) > 1)
        sort1(x, n-s, s);
}

/**
 * Swaps x[a] with x[b].
 */
private static void swap(int x[], int a, int b) {
    int t = x[a];
    x[a] = x[b];
    x[b] = t;
}

/**
 * Swaps x[a .. (a+n-1)] with x[b .. (b+n-1)].
 */
private static void vecswap(int x[], int a, int b, int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++, a++, b++)
        swap(x, a, b);
}

/**
 * Returns the index of the median of the three indexed integers.
 */
private static int med3(int x[], int a, int b, int c) {
    return (x[a] < x[b] ?
            (x[b] < x[c] ? b : x[a] < x[c] ? c : a) :
            (x[b] > x[c] ? b : x[a] > x[c] ? c : a));
}
```

Comment: Be aware that since the above is copied (with modification) from the Sun / Oracle GPLv2 codebase, if >you< use it in your application, then your application is also subject to the GPLv2 constraints.  In short, if you distribute binaries, you must also make your source code available.  If you don't understand this talk to a lawyer.  (Note that Oracle has a reputation for being legally aggressive ...)