# Why the passed array cannot use lambda function

Tags: java, lambda

Why I have to create a new Integer array `B` to use the `Arrays.sort` and lambda function?

```java
class Solution {
    public int[] sortArrayByParity(int[] A) {
        Integer[] B = new Integer[A.length];
        for (int t = 0; t < A.length; ++t)
            B[t] = A[t];

        Arrays.sort(B, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a%2, b%2));

        for (int t = 0; t < A.length; ++t)
            A[t] = B[t];
        return A;
    }
}
```

Trying to sort the original array directly - `Arrays.sort(A, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a%2, b%2))` - gives the following compilation error:

> The method sort(int[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (int[], ( a,  b) -> {})

Comment: So what happens if you dont make the copy? What is the error?

Comment: What happens if you *don't* create a new array? Please elaborate on your problems. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort arrays of primitive types in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215271/sort-arrays-of-primitive-types-in-descending-order) and [Sort an array of primitives with a custom comparator and without converting to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666377/sort-an-array-of-primitives-with-a-custom-comparator-and-without-converting-to-o)

Answer (score 2):

The variant of `Arrays.sort` you are using, which accepts a `Comparator` argument, expects an array of some reference type as input, so you cannot pass a primitive array to it.

Therefore  you can't pass the primitive array `A` to it.

You must convert your primitive array (`int[]`) to an array of reference type (`Integer[]`) in order to use `void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`.

However, you can reduce your code by using `Stream`s:

```
public int[] sortArrayByParity(int[] A) {
    return Arrays.stream(A).boxed().sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a % 2)).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Though this specific task can be better handled by partitioning and copying back.

Comment: @XiaodongZheng you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

below is the method signature of  Arrays.sort method

> public static  void sort(T[] a, Comparator c)

You can see that it expects a Generic type and primitives are not reference types.