# How to sort prime number array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I would like to sort this array of numbers by their prime factorization. But I am currently unsure how to begin sorting. I am thinking of using hash map to store the key and the prime factorization as an array and sort the array of values using a comparator. Here is a visualization of what i am trying to achieve:

Can someone help please? Thank you!

**Input:**

```
3, 4, 8, 9, 12
```

**Edit:** The number is sorted in this order because numbers are differentiated by the lower prime factor first (which is 2 in this case) followed by 3.

```
Prime Factorization of 4: 2 2 
Prime Factorization of 8: 2 2 2 
Prime Factorization of 12: 2 2 3 
Prime Factorization of 3: 3 
Prime Factorization of 9: 3 3 
and so on...
```

**Output:**

```
4, 8, 12, 3, 9
```

**Here is my Code:**

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 3, 4, 8, 9 ,12 };
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Prime Factorization of " + array[i] + ": ");
            getPrimeFactors(array[i]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void getPrimeFactors(int number) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
            while (number % i == 0) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                number /= i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, explain result of sort: `4, 8, 12, 3, 9`. Why this order?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look again,

Comment: I have examined your snippet code I think you are on the right way. your next step, array and its corresponding should be store in hash map like you said. If I were you I would code the way you do.

Comment: that would be a great idea to try. thanks ilyas!

Answer (score 3):

To use custom comparator you would need to cast your array to `Integer[]`.

[Sort an array of primitives with a custom comparator and without converting to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666377/sort-an-array-of-primitives-with-a-custom-comparator-and-without-converting-to-o)

You can do it easily with `streams`

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 3, 4, 8, 9 ,12 };
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> factorizations = new HashMap<>();

        for(int num : array) {
            if(factorizations.containsKey(num)) {
                continue;
            }

            factorizations.put(num, factorization(num));
        }

        array = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().sorted((a, b) -> {
            List<Integer> aFactorization = factorizations.get(a);
            List<Integer> bFactorization = factorizations.get(b);

            for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(aFactorization.size(), bFactorization.size()); i++) {
                if(!aFactorization.get(i).equals(bFactorization.get(i))) {
                    return aFactorization.get(i) - bFactorization.get(i);
                }
            }

            if(aFactorization.size() != bFactorization.size()) {
                return aFactorization.size() - bFactorization.size();
            }

            return 0;
        }).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).toArray();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public static List<Integer> factorization(int number) {
        List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 2; i <= number / i; i++) {
            while (number % i == 0) {
                factors.add(i);
                number /= i;
            }
        }

        if (number > 1) {
            factors.add(number);
        }

        return factors;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[4, 8, 12, 3, 9]
```

[Java stream boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--)

Comment: thanks! i didnt thought of using streams in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of using a map to store the prime factorizations, and a custom comparator to sort the array, is solid:

```
Integer[] array = {3, 4, 8, 9, 12};
    
Map<Integer, Integer[]> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int a : array) map.putIfAbsent(a, getPrimeFactors(a));
    
Arrays.sort(array, (a, b) -> Arrays.compare(map.get(a), map.get(b)));
    
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Output:

```
[4, 8, 12, 3, 9]
```

Where we have:

```
public static Integer[] getPrimeFactors(int n)
{
    List<Integer> pfs = new ArrayList<>();

    for (; n % 2 == 0; n /= 2) pfs.add(2);

    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)
        for (; n % i == 0; n /= i) pfs.add(i);

    if (n > 1) pfs.add(n);

    return pfs.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First rewrite your `getPrimeFactors` method to return the list of prime factors:

```
public static List<Integer> getPrimeFactors(int number) {
        List<Integer> primeFactors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
            while (number % i == 0) {
                primeFactors.add(i);
                number /= i;
            }
        }
        return primeFactors;
    }
```

Now, your high-level goal is to sort the prime factorization in lexicographic  order. To this end, we convert each list of prime factors to a `String`, mapping each prime factor to a character. Then we sort by the `String` version of the list of prime factors. Finally, we output the list. Here is the `main` method rewritten to do just that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 3, 4, 8, 9, 12 };
        String[][] numsAndFactors = new String[array.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String primeFactorsToChars = "";
            List<Integer> primeFactors = getPrimeFactors(array[i]);
            for (int primeNumber : primeFactors) {
                primeFactorsToChars += (char) (primeNumber + 48);
            }
            numsAndFactors[i] = new String[] {Integer.toString(array[i]), primeFactorsToChars};

        }
        Arrays.sort(numsAndFactors, (a, b) -> a[1].compareTo(b[1]));

        for (String[] numberAndFactors : numsAndFactors) {
            System.out.print("Prime factorization of " + numberAndFactors[0] + ": ");
            String factors = numberAndFactors[1];
            for (char c : factors.toCharArray()) {
                System.out.print((int) (c - 48) + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Prime factorization of 4: 2, 2, 
Prime factorization of 8: 2, 2, 2,
Prime factorization of 12: 2, 2, 3,
Prime factorization of 3: 3,
Prime factorization of 9: 3, 3,
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. would it be possible without stream?

Comment: @BlueTree I have updated my solution to not use `stream`, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

To do the same without comparators, using a simple selection sort (not as efficient) is as follows. This does not require using collections.

```
public class prime {
    public static String getPrimeFactors(int number) {
        String primeFactors = "";
        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
            while (number % i == 0) {
                //System.out.print(i + " ");
                primeFactors+= i + " ";
                number /= i;
            }
        }
        return primeFactors;
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {3,4,8,9,12};
        String factorArr[] = new String[arr.length];
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            factorArr[i] = getPrimeFactors(arr[i]);
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length - 1; i++) {
            int min = i;
            for(int j = i+1; j<arr.length; j++) {
                if(factorArr[j].compareTo(factorArr[min]) < 0) {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            int temp = arr[min];
            arr[min] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
            
            String temp2 = factorArr[min];
            factorArr[min] = factorArr[i];
            factorArr[i] = temp2;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number: " + arr[i] + " & Factors: " + factorArr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I'm just storing the prime factorizations as an array of strings with indexes corresponding to that in the original. Then we sort the factorization strings and when doing the swap also make the change in our original array of numbers to keep the index corresponding to each other.

As a result, we have 2 arrays, one with the initial numbers sorted in the order you want, and the other being their prime factor counterparts.
While this isn't the most efficient way of doing it, it should be fairly easy to understand and make changes to if u require later.

Comment: I agree its not the most efficient but this would suffice my visualization.  Many thanks!