# Sorting arrays of primitive types in descending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

In Java, how do I sort a float[] array in reverse order with Arrays.sort()? Or at least some function using the same algorithm.

Please avoid any kind of comments about using `Float` instead of `float`. Also reversing the array after it has been sorted isn't an option either as it's a very critical piece of code.

Comment: I'm puzzled, you say _nondecreasingly_ which I translate into 'increasingly' yet you write _sort [...] in reverse order_. So what exactly are you after?

Comment: Oh, I'll fix it. I just meant reverse order, so decreasingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Array Sort descending?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694751/java-array-sort-descending)

Comment: @Betlista No, that was not about primitive arrays.

Comment: @Betlista read through the question + answer: OP wants to sort an array of primitives

Comment: There is an answer for primitives also - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22065663/384674

Comment: @Betista Please I encourage you to read through my full question (which I tried to keep short) before flagging this as already answered with a non appropiate question. 

Also, regarding your second reply, and having read that, I also stated clearly that reversing the array after sorting wasn't an option for me.

If you could remove that flag that would be much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: I also want to say that "This can't be done with the Java libraries" is a perfectly valid answer as long as it's true. I was just hoping that there could be a way but it doesn't seem like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest taking the source code from Arrays.sort(float[]), copy it in a new method in your project, then modify it in the relevant place to reverse (negate) the comparison result.

It should return exactly what you wanted - a reverse-sorted array, using exactly the same algorithm.

Comment: That looks like the best thing one can possibly do to actually solve this. Too bad Java libraries don't implement this out of the box...

Answer (score 1):

Javas `Arrays.sort()` and `ArrayUtils.reverse()` from Apache Commons.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I already stated in my question that: "reversing the array after it has been sorted isn't an option either as it's a very critical piece of code."

Comment: @Setzer22 _Very critical p.o.c._, okay but how often do you have to traverse the array? Do you do it in an indexed fashion? if so, why not sort and revert the index?

Comment: Reversing the array should be done very quick as against sorting. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/217477/748524 . The alternative was to wrap the primitives into Floats but you don't want to do that.

Comment: @Stephan Correct. Reversing the array is a cheap O(_n_) operation. The sorting using `Arrays.sort()` is on average O(_n_ log _n_).

Comment: With n being around 25-35 it makes no difference (nlogn) vs (logn). Reversing the array after sorting is like doubling the sorting time. If you're interested I'm trying to implement a solver for the quadratic assignment problem. That, in its core uses a lot of matrix operations to compute a bound for the branch and bound procedure, and to do that, it has to sort a LOT of small vectors. (It's an O(n!) algorithm performing about 2n sorts at each step). 

I feel it's more than justified to ask for an efficient way to do this naturally, which would be equivalent to change < for >.

Comment: @okiharaherbst Regarding traversing the array backwards seems like the easy choice, as we have to implement a minimum scalar product. We'll stick into that although that doesn't answer the question, but thanks.

Comment: @Setzer22 Assuming that you're going to traverse your array in a for loop, I see no penalty for accessing your array entries as `array[array.length-1-i]`. If you must know, having been TAing back in the days, I would have actually penalized you for reversing the array instead of accessing it in reverse order. Also, make sure you do not hand-code your matrix-matrix/vector ops.

Comment: Well, the hardware assumes that arrays are always traversed from 0 to n-1, and some optimisations like precaching are built on top of this, but this is going a little bit over the top. I think we all agree that being able to sort in reverse order would be the best option, but as it's not avaliable in Java libraries I'll go with backwards traversing. That being said I'm implementing a particular vector operation, a minimum scalar product, which I haven't been able to find anywhere, that's why I'm doing it by hand if that's what you were saying. It's not like a matrix product which is common.

Comment: @Setzer22 The minimum scalar product is sheer fantasy, therefore it's not available in linear algebra libraries. That said, if you're doing one of those coding exercises, I'd go with implementing the descending sorting by hand and use `sdot` for the dot product.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by sheer fantasy. I'm not on what you might say as a "coding" exercise as it goes way beyond doing this operation. But anyway I'll go with sorting both the same way and traversing them in reverse order, which will lead to the same result.

Answer (score -1):

```
Arrays.sort(array,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: This won't work with primitive type arrays. The compiler complains as there are no comparators for float, just Float. This is the message: "The method sort(float[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (float[], Comparator<Object>)"