# Sort a 2D array of structs in Java

Tags: java, double, multidimensional-array

Given the 2D Array, PearsonArray[100][100], how would I sort in descending order based on the double PearsonArray[][].pearson_correlation? The rows are just intergers and the columns are structs (as depicted below).

Result data looks like this:

ROW 0:

[0]==>[TEST_USER:201,TRAIN_USER:13, CORRELATION:0.2222194792894441

[1]==>[TEST_USER:201,TRAIN_USER:15, CORRELATION:0.9549380840555494

[2]==>[TEST_USER:201,TRAIN_USER:52, CORRELATION:0.8741572761215378

[3]==>[TEST_USER:201,TRAIN_USER:54, CORRELATION:0.9930549935286451

[4]==>[TEST_USER:201,TRAIN_USER:62, CORRELATION:0.37139067635410394

[5]==>[TEST_USER:201,TRAIN_USER:63, CORRELATION:0.8904703363154174

```
public class myPearsonStruct {
    int testUserID;
    int trainUserID;
    double pearson_correlation;

    public myPearsonStruct(int tester, int trainer, double correlation){
        this.testUserID = tester;
        this.trainUserID = trainer;
        this.pearson_correlation = correlation;
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort order to you want to apply?  2D array sorting is kinda weird.

Comment: I would like to sort based on the double, pearson_correlation, in desc order. For instance, in the sample output above, I would want the entry where TRAIN_USER == 54 to appear on top because that has the highest pearson correlation.

Comment: That looks like a 1-dimensional array to me.  If it is indeed two-dimensional, then "on top" doesn't make any sense.  "On top" could mean [0][0], or [99][99], or [50][50], [100][0], or anything else!

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215271/sort-arrays-of-primitive-types-in-descending-order

Comment: You've tried to use Comparator?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to sort the instances of class myPearsonStruct (maybe you want to have Capital "M" as class name) in one dimensional in order of the pearson_correlation field.

You may make use of the Arrays.sort method to do sorting. But you have to convert your 2-dimensional array to one dimensional first. How it is order is not really matter as you will do sorting anyway.

For example,

```
myPearsonStruct[] mpsArray = new myPearsonStruct[100*100];
for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
  for(int j=0;j<100;j++) {
    mpsArray[i*100+j] = PearsonArray[i][j];
  }
}
```

Then you need to implement an interface Comparable to specify how order is determined.

```
public class PearsonComparator implements Comparator<myPearsonStruct> {
  public int compare(myPearsonStruct o1, myPearsonStruct o2) {
    // descending order
    if (o1.pearson_correlation < o2.pearson_correlation) return 1;
    else if (o1.pearson_correlation > o2.pearson_correlation) return -1;
    else return 0;
  }
}
```

With two piece of code in place, you can sort the data easily with this:

```
Arrays.sort(mpsArray, new PearsonComparator());
```

The result will be placed at the mpsArray.