# Getting the largest k elements of a double array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The problem I am facing is this one:

I have an array of `double`s from which I want to keep the top `k` greater values.

1. I have seen some implementations involving `Arrays.sort`. For example in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215271/sort-arrays-of-primitive-types-in-descending-order) with relative issue it is suggested to use this approach.
2. Since I am only interested in the first `k` elements I have also experimented with `MinMaxPriorityQueue`. I have created a `MinMaxPriorityQueue` with a `maximumSize`:

Of course there is again autoboxing.

```
Builder<Comparable> builder = MinMaxPriorityQueue.maximumSize(maximumSize);
MinMaxPriorityQueue<Double> top2 = builder.create();
```

The problem is that the order is the ascending one that it's the opposite of the one I want. So I cannot use it this way.

To state the problem's real parameters my arrays is about `50` elements long and I am interested in up to the top `k = 5`  elements.

So is there any way to bypass this problem using the second approach? Should I stay with the first one even though I don't really need all elements sorted? Do you know if there is any significant difference in speed performance (I will have to use this in a lot of situations so that's where the speed is needed)? Is there any other solution I could use?

As for the performance, I know I can theoretically check it myself but I am a bit out of time and if someone have any solution I am happy to hear it (or read it anyway).

Comment: `Arrays.sort(new double[]{...})` doesn't involve autoboxing.

Comment: Yes but it does not work with `double[]` either in reverse order

Comment: And why do you need reverse order? Just sort it, and take the last `k` elements.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about this one.

Comment: If you have only 50 elements then you're too worried about performance, unless you are going to run your program in a very small device (an old android phone?). Are you going to scale this to deal with very large arrays?

Comment: @morgano Hint: Any android phone won't have a problem with 50 elements^^ Even a microprocessor should be able to handle this.

Comment: @AlexR yes, that's why I used an question mark. but don't assume that the app running this code will be the only one being executed in the device, it would be competing for RAM and CPU with the other apps

Comment: Maybe it's clear but the above process is going to happen a lot so any micro-impovement could make a difference. That's why I am interested in the faster solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have like 50 elements, as noted in my comment, just sort it and take the last `k` elements. It's 2 lines only:

```
public static double[] largests(double[] arr, int k) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, arr.length - k, arr.length);
}
```

This modifies (sorts) the original array. If you want your original array unmodified, you only need +1 line:

```
public static double[] largests2(double[] arr, int k) {
    arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, arr.length - k, arr.length);
}
```

Comment: This will alter the order of elements in `arr`, note that when you are trying to work with it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Added a modified version which doesn't modify the original array.

Comment: That's my first algorithm^^ Note the running time accoring to the javadoc is `O(N*log(N))`. I have written up one with `O(N*k*log(k))` wich is faster for small `k` and large `N`, especially linear if `k` is constant.

Comment: Yes, I just made use of `Arrays` to halve the lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.arraycopy` on a sorted array:

```
double[] getMaxElements(double[] input, int k) {
    double[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length);
    Arrays.sort(temp); // Sort a copy to keep input as it is since Arrays.sort works in-place.
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(temp, temp.length - k, temp.length); // Fetch largest elements
}
```

For 50 elements, it is much faster to sort an array than to mess with generics and comparables.
I will write up an additional "fast" algorithm...

```
double[] getMaxElements2(double[] input, int k) {
    double[] res = new double[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) res[i] = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY; // Make them as small as possible.
    for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) // Look at every element
        if (res[0] < input[j]) { // Keep the current element
            res[0] = input[j];
            Arrays.sort(res); // Keep the lowest kept element at res[0]
        }
    return res;
}
```

This is `O(N*k*log(k))` while the first one is `O(N*log(N))`.

Comment: Note that `Arrays.copyOf()` requires a length too (else compile error).