# Getting the indices of an unsorted double array after sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indices

This question comes as a companion of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802052/getting-the-largest-k-elements-of-a-double-array) that regarded fastest sorting of a double array.

Now I want to get the top-`k` indices corresponding to the unsorted array.

I have implemented this version which (unfortunately) uses autoboxing and `HashMap` as proposed in some answers including this [one](http://www.coderanch.com/t/451158/java/java/Helping-Sorting-Array-Doubles-Index):

```
HashMap<Double, Integer> map = new HashMap<Double, Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < numClusters; i++) {
    map.put(scores[i], i);
}
Arrays.sort(scores);
HashSet<Integer> topPossibleClusters = new HashSet<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < numClusters; i++) {
    topPossibleClusters.add(map.get(scores[numClusters - (i+1)]));
}
```

As you can see this uses a `HashMap` with keys the `Double` values of the original array and as values the indices of the original array.
So, after sorting the original array I just retrieve it from the `map`.

I also use `HashSet` as I am interested in deciding if an `int` is included in this set, using `.contains()` method. (I don't know if this makes a difference since as I mentioned in the other question my arrays are small -50 elements-). If this does not make a difference point it out though.

I am not interested in the value per se, only the indices.

My question is whether there is a faster approach to go with it?

Comment: I would way using a `TreeMap` is much more obvious - that way you can simply get the `HeadMap`. But a more pertinent point is that in a `Map` keys are unique! If you have duplicate values your results will end up being somewhat odd.

Comment: I don't think I have duplicates so that won't be a problem. `TreeMap` would do the sorting implicitly I guess. I will consider your proposition.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of interlinking/interlocking collections lends itself to fragile, easily broken, hard to debug, unmaintainable code.

Instead create an object:

```
class Data {
    double value;
    int originalIndex;
}
```

Create an array of Data objects storing the original value and index.

Sort them using a custom comparator that looks at data.value and sorts descending.

Now the top X items in your array are the ones you want and you can just look at the `value` and `originalIndex` as you need them.

Comment: Ok, your point is understood, but for the main part of method speed won't make a difference I guess, right?

Comment: @Eypros It will be slightly slower at the start/end as it will need to allocate and construct the objects and then garbage collect them after use. It will be much faster while processing though as there is no need to maintain/build the HashMap and no HashMap lookups.

Answer (score 1):

As [Tim points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25804683/2071828) linking a multiple collections is rather errorprone. I would suggest using a `TreeMap` as this would allow for a standalone solution.

Lets say you have `double[] data`, first copy it to a `TreeMap`:

```
final TreeMap<Double, Integer> dataWithIndex = new TreeMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    dataWithIndex.put(data[i], i);
}
```

N.B. You can declare `dataWithIndex` as a `NavigableMap` to be less specific, but it's so much longer and it doesn't really add much as there is only one implementation in the JDK.

This will populate the `Map` in `O(n lg n)` time as each `put` is `O(lg n)` - this is the same complexity as sorting. In reality it will be probably be a little slower, but it will *scale in the same way*.

Now, say you need the first `k` elements, you need to first find the `k`th element - this is `O(k)`:

```
final Iterator<Double> keyIter = dataWithIndex.keySet().iterator();
double kthKey;
for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    kthKey = keyIter.next();
}
```

Now you just need to get the sub-map that has all the entries upto the kth entry:

```
final Map<Double, Integer> topK = dataWithIndex.headMap(kthKey, true);
```

If you only need to do this once, then with Java 8 you can do something like this:

```
List<Entry<Double, Integer>> topK = IntStream.range(0, data.length).
        mapToObj(i -> new SimpleEntry<>(data[i], i)).
        sorted(comparing(Entry::getKey)).
        limit(k).
        collect(toList());
```

i.e. take an `IntStream` for the indices of `data` and `mapToObj` to an `Entry` of the `data[i] => i` (using the `AbsractMap.SimpleEntry` implementation). Now sort that using `Entry::getKey` and limit the size of the `Stream` to `k` entries. Now simply collect the result to a `List`. This has the advantage of not clobbering duplicate entries in the `data` array.

It is almost exactly what Tim suggests in his answer, but using an existing JDK class.

This method is also `O(n lg n)`. The catch is that if the `TreeMap` approach is reused then it's `O(n lg n)` to build the `Map` but only `O(k)` to reuse it. If you want to use the Java 8 solution with reuse then you can do:

```
List<Entry<Double, Integer>> sorted = IntStream.range(0, data.length).
        mapToObj(i -> new SimpleEntry<>(data[i], i)).
        sorted(comparing(Entry::getKey)).
        collect(toList());
```

i.e. don't limit the size to `k` elements. Now, to get the first `k` elements you just need to do:

```
List<Entry<Double, Integer>> subList = sorted.subList(0, k);
```

The magic of this is that it's `O(1)`.