# (Java) Method that sorts a Char array into its reverse alphabetical order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Just to be on the same page, I'm not looking to sort a String array into its reverse alphabetical order, I'm looking forward to doing this for a Char Array.

Here's my attempted code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ReverseSortDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[] unorderedLetters; 
        unorderedLetters = new char[]{'b', 'm', 'z', 'a', 'u'};
        reverseSort(unorderedLetters); 
        for (int i = 0 ; i < unorderedLetters.length; i++ )
            System.out.println(unorderedLetters[i]);
    }

    //method that sorts a char array into its reverse alphabetical order
    public static void reverseSort(char[] values){

        Arrays.sort(values);
        for (int i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            values[values.length-1-i]=values[i];
        }
    }

}
```

The output I'm getting is this:

```
z
u
m
u
z
```

BUT, my desired output as you guys know is this:

```
z
u
m
b
a
```

So, how do I deal with this? Is there a way, and if possible, an easier way to do this (e.g. builtin method) which I'm not aware of, so that I can start getting lazy with my code?

Answer (score -3):

You Could try the `sort` method in the `java.util.Arrays` class.

```
Arrays.sort(values, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Here `values` is your array.

Comment: This does not work whatsoever. Please test out what you're going to suggest me before answering the question.

Comment: I must mention this. The Array shouldn't be of primitive data types.

Comment: Then don't send an "answer" that does not answer my question.

Comment: You could easily wrap primitive data types into classes. However, if you prefer not to, read this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215271/sort-arrays-of-primitive-types-in-descending-order

Comment: As said earlier, this solution will NOT work on primitives. It will only work on a class. Also, the link provided is useless if you're not going to download that Java Primitive library.