# Sort array and reflect the changes in another array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array of doubles, in Java : `arr1` which I want to sort. Most probably the first option would be the utility method `Arrays.sort(double[])`.

The idea is that I want the same changes (e.g. value at `index i` is interchanged with value at `index j` in `arr1`) to be reflected in another array of integers: `arr2` (in the sense that the values at the same indexes are changed also in `arr2`).

Is there a simple way (a trick) to accomplish this in Java? Or the only way is to implement the sorting algorithm by myself?

**UPDATE**: I see that people recommend replacing the two arrays with one array of objects containing the 2 values (one from `arr1` and one from `arr2`). Wouldn't this bring some efficiency penalties. In other words, isn't it less efficient to sort an array of objects than an array of primitive types (doubles in this case) ?

The data is completely static. It's large (it fits in memory) but static.

Comment: Have an array of indexes. Don't sort the value array, sort the index array. Then use the index array to point to both value arrays. See the solution in:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859261/get-the-indices-of-an-array-after-sorting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112234/sorting-matched-arrays-in-java

Comment: This is what would be called an "external sort".

Comment: To address your edit: the sort may be less efficent (metrics would be required to say for sure), but you are going to gain efficiency by not having to sort 2 arrays or have complex index mapping during value lookups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than trying to maintain sorted parallel arrays, a cleaner solution would be to create a class that encapsulates both of your data values, and just have one array of objects.

(But to answer your question, there is no built-in way to do this in Java.  Implementing your own sort routine that keeps two arrays sorted based on values in one of them would work for a small amount of data that isn't likely to change, but it would be difficult to maintain.)

Comment: Sorting an array of objects is as efficient as sorting an array of doubles ?

Comment: @Razvan Sorting an array of objects is going to be extremely efficient.  I doubt you'd be able to measure the difference.

Comment: just thought I should mention the `Comparable` interface for your new object. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: Sorting an array of objects is more efficient than building your own sort that probably won't be as smart.  Those are your only options -- Java doesn't have a built-in way to propagate the changes to another array.

Answer (score 1):

One solution which is doesn't impact the performance of sorting, ie still O(nlog(n)) time complexity.

- Use a map to store  `array[i] -> i`
- Sort the array
- Iterate over the sorted array, and for each value, use it as a key for the map to retrieve the original index.

Edit: Raihan comment make me look miserable :(

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way....

**-** Convert this `array` into `ArrayList` using the `Arrays.asList()`

**-** Create another List Object Reference Variable and assign the same ArrayList object to it, Now any changes to the first ArrayList will be reflected to the Second ArrayList.

**Eg:**

```
double[] array = new double[10];

ArrayList<Double> arList_1 = new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(array));

ArrayList<Double> arList_2 = arList2;
```

**Now for sorting, there are 2 options:**

**-** Use `java.lang.Comparable` Interface, if you want to sort it **in only 1 way**.

**-** Use `java.util.Comparator` Interface, if you want to sort it in **more than 1 way.**

Answer (score 0):

Note sure what are you looking for but one other work around could be like this.

Create a map to maintain the relation between `arr1` and `arr2` elments

```
      Map<Double, Double> myLocalMap<Double, Double>();
      for(int ind=0; indx < arr1.length; indx++){
           myLocalMap.put(Double.valueOf(arr1[indx]), Double.valueOf(arr2[indx]));
      }
```

Now sort `arr1` as you said:

```
     Arrays.sort(arr1);
```

Once `arr1` is sorted, update `arr2` as below:

```
      for(int ind=0; indx < arr1.length; indx++){
          arr2[indx] = myLocalMap.get(arr1[indx]).doubleValue();
      }
```