# Java: How to sort two corresponding arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
First array:
25, 20, 50, 30, 12, 11...

Second Array: 
New York, New Jersey, Detroit, Atlanta, Chicago, Los Angeles
```

Every two cities from the second array correspond to one value from the first.

Example: New York and New Jersey would correspond to 25, Detroit and Atlanta would correspond to 20 and so on.

I want to reorder the first Array's numbers in descending order (50, 30, 25, 20...), but I also want the cities of the second array to be shifted accordingly so that they have the same value before and after the sort.

How do I accomplish this task? (I can use either an ArrayList or an Array, whichever works out simpler)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824423/sort-array-and-reflect-the-changes-in-another-array?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112234/sorting-matched-arrays-in-java?lq=1 (unlike .NET, Java does not have standard library support for multi-array sorting)

Comment: Are the values in each array unique?

Comment: You might prefer using a Map in java for something like that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824423/sort-array-and-reflect-the-changes-in-another-array?lq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You can use TreeMap:

```
Map<Integer, String[]> map = new TreeMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<firstArray.length;i++){
   map.put(firstArray[i], new String[]{secondArray[i * 2], secondArray[i*2+1]});
}
```

And this map will be sorted by key natural order.

But I would suggest you to make container class. Something like:

```
public class CityPair{
  public int value;
  public String[] cities = new String[2]; 
}
```

Now you can fill the list by your data:

```
...   
ArrayList list = new ArrayList<CityPair>();

for(int i=0; i<firstArray.length; i++){
  CityPair pair = new CityPair();
  pair.value = firstArray[i];
  pair.cities[0] = secondArray[i*2];
  pair.cities[1] = secondArray[i*2+1];
  list.add(pair);
}
...
```

As you see, I didn't check indexes for "index out of bounds", but you should. After that you can sort your list. You could do it manually using for example [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) algorithm, but better way is write custom comparator:

```
public class CityPairComparator implements Comparator<CityPair> {
    @Override
    public int compare(CityPair pair1, CityPair pair2) {
        return Integer.compare(pair1.value, pair2.value);
    }
}
```

Now you can sort your list with Collections utility class:

```
Collections.sort(list, new CityPairComparator());
```

With this approch you can replace `String[] cities` in `CityPair` class for `ArrayList<Sting> cities`. Then it's will be able to add more than two cities per value.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 provides a slightly more elegant way to do this without needing a separate map:

```
int[] array1;
String[] array2;

array2 = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(array1, array2))
    .boxed().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> array1[i]))
    .map(i -> array2[i])
    .toArray(array2);
```

The boxing is only required because `IntStream` does not have a `sorted` method with a custom `Comparator`. I'm not sure why not.

If you want to end up with a `List` then use `.collect(Collectors.toList())` instead of `toArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (4 line) solution that also handles mismatched array lengths:

```
int[] numbers = {25, 20, 50};
String[] cities = {"New York", "New Jersey", "Detroit", "Atlanta", "Chicago", "Los Angeles"};

Map<Object, Object> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(Integer.class::cast, Integer::compare).reversed());
for (Iterator<?> n = Arrays.stream(numbers).iterator(),
    s = Arrays.stream(String.join(",", cities).split(",(?=(([^,]*,){2})*[^,]*,[^,]*$)")).iterator();
    n.hasNext() && s.hasNext(); )
    map.put(n.next(), s.next());
numbers = map.keySet().stream().map(String::valueOf).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
cities = map.values().stream().map(String::valueOf).map(s -> s.split(",")).flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray(String[]::new);
```

This creates two iterators on the fly from streams of each array, both typed to `Object` to allow dual initialization within the for loop. The cities array is first joined into one string then split into pairs-as-a-String (using an appropriate regex). The elements of both iterators populate a `TreeMap`, which has a reversed `Integer` comparator.

Because `TreeMaps` iterate in *sorted* order, a stream of `keySet()` and `values()` can be used to generate the resulting arrays.

The `for` loop's terminal condition checks both iterators to see if there's a next element available, which causes excess elements of the longer array to be ignored if the arrays aren't of equal length.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a solution like this, It is using Arraylist as per your requirement :

First I have created a new data structure for your operation. As each value will hold two city name:

```
 public class Citizen implements Comparable<Citizen>  {

    private int citizenId;
    private String subjectOne;
    private String subjectTwo;


    public Citizen(int rollNumber, String subjectOne, String subjectTwo){
        this.citizenId = rollNumber;
        this.subjectOne = subjectOne;
        this.subjectTwo = subjectTwo;
    }

    public int getRollNumber() {
        return citizenId;
    }
    public void setRollNumber(int rollNumber) {
        this.citizenId = rollNumber;
    }
    public String getSubjectOne() {
        return subjectOne;
    }
    public void setSubjectOne(String subjectOne) {
        this.subjectOne = subjectOne;
    }
    public String getSubjectTwo() {
        return subjectTwo;
    }
    public void setSubjectTwo(String subjectTwo) {
        this.subjectTwo = subjectTwo;
    }


        public int compareTo(Citizen comparestu) {
            int compareage=((Citizen)comparestu).getRollNumber();
            /* For Ascending order*/
            return this.citizenId-compareage;

            /* For Descending order do like this */
            //return compareage-this.studentage;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[ rollno=" + citizenId + ", subjectOne=" + subjectOne + ", subjectTwo=" + subjectTwo + "]";
        }   
}
```

As you can see here the parameter for comparison is taken as citizenID using implementation of Comparable interface.

now to call :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Citizen> studentList = new ArrayList<Citizen>();

        studentList.add(new Citizen(25, "New York", "New Jersey"));
        studentList.add(new Citizen(20, "Detroit", "Atlanta"));
        studentList.add(new Citizen(50, "Chicago", "Los Angeles"));
        studentList.add(new Citizen(30, "Kolkata", "Delhi"));
        studentList.add(new Citizen(12, "Munmbai", "Baranasi"));
        studentList.add(new Citizen(11, "Bangalore", "Goa"));



        Collections.sort(studentList);
           for(Citizen student: studentList){
                System.out.println(student);
           }
    }
```

output :

```
[ rollno=11, subjectOne=Bangalore, subjectTwo=Goa]
[ rollno=12, subjectOne=Munmbai, subjectTwo=Baranasi]
[ rollno=20, subjectOne=Detroit, subjectTwo=Atlanta]
[ rollno=25, subjectOne=New York, subjectTwo=New Jersey]
[ rollno=30, subjectOne=Kolkata, subjectTwo=Delhi]
[ rollno=50, subjectOne=Chicago, subjectTwo=Los Angeles]
```